# Saving custom fields in devise User model in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I made a devise User model and added additional fields to it. When I create and account everything works fine, only with email, pw and pw conf.

I then want to allow the user to go to edit page and fill in the optional additional fields.
But, when they submit, everything is saved as nil.

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in){ |u| u.permit(:email, :password) }
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up){ |u| u.permit(:name, :username, :about,  :email, :password, :password_confirmation)}
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update){ |u| u.permit(:name, :username, :about, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
   end

   def update
     self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
     if resource.update_with_password(user_params)
       if is_navigational_format?
         flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ? :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
         set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
       end
       sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
       respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
     else
       clean_up_passwords resource
       respond_with resource
     end
   end

   def user_params 
     params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation, :name, :username, :about) 
   end
 end
```

I get this output in the console,

```
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
 Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EG8FtCTBohuG2uwUvIqmY7KTsmYY1nMAXqTfc0Li+eQ=", 
 "user"=>{"email"=>"a@a.com", "name"=>"Aaron", "username"=>"", "about"=>"", 
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}

User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: name, username, about
```

But nothing is saved in the database when I check in the console (with User.last). I am stuck, and have looked and have no idea what is wrong...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Rails4 we have strong parameters so please

Add following line to your application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?
  def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  For those new to Devise, it might be helpful to know you have to sanitize the same parameters for other actions you might have such as :edit (if the user can edit).  Of course you will also need to write a rails migration to add those fields to the Devise model and generate the views for the login and sign up screens (see Devise docs for how to generate views).

Comment: I also had to use devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { ... } to get the edit of my user to work

Comment: I had to add `:current_password` within the `:account_update` for anyone who's app requires username's password to update information

Comment: Note that for Devise 4 [the parameter sanitizer API has changed](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

After working on something similar to this, I settled on using Application Controller, then afterward found that the Devise Documentation is fairly straightforward for this in their strong parameters section and gives an alternative to using Application Controller. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Below is the approach with Application Controller which worked for me.

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

      before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

      private

      def configure_permitted_parameters
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up){ |u| u.permit(:name, :username, :about,  :email, :password, :password_confirmation)}        
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update){ |u| u.permit(:name, :username, :about, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }          
      end

    end
```

This should work the same and it directly overwrites methods in `Devise::RegistrationController`.

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      private

      def configure_sign_up_params
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up){ |u| u.permit(:name, :username, :about,  :email, :password, :password_confirmation)}
      end

      def configure_account_update_params
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update){ |u| u.permit(:name, :username, :about, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 1):

First produce new field.
for reference
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Do you have add your new fields in user controller parameter?

```
   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

In the application controller

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)}

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)}
  end
```

In your registration form that override devise add this

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
     skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:ipn_notification]
  def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

After that add your new fields in all views _form,show,edit,index.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4.2, this is how I did. 
I have User Model on which devise is applied. 
Use this command "rails generate devise:controllers users" to generate custom controllers.
I have added "username" name attribute to my User Model

In my controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
 before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
 #rest of code as generated

   protected

    # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_sign_up_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
    end

   # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
   def configure_account_update_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
   end
```

In Routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations"}
```