# Devise doesn't insert username into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have following ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_filter :require_vote

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email])
    # devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end

  private

  def require_vote
    unless cookies[:voted]
      redirect_to vote_path
    end
  end
end
```

Also I have following User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :pictures
  attr_accessor :username
  validates :username, presence: true
end
```

And when I'm registering, in logs I see that it doesn't actually inserts username in database, but it gets username in parameters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18567908/2681997

Comment: @ABPrime I get this undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007f849cc4aea0> Did you mean? fork

Comment: which rails version are you using ?

Comment: Don't use attr_accessor - lots of questions/answers on that topic.

Comment: @ABPrime and same thing but with permit method instead of for does same thing as I wrote in question

Comment: @FrederickCheung should I use protected then?

Comment: @FrederickCheung your answer worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include CanCan::ControllerAdditions
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  protected

  def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
    registration_params = [:name, :email, :phone, :skype, :site, :description, :image, :image_cache, :password, :password_confirmation, :surname, :patronymic]

    if params[:action] == 'update'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
        u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
      end
    elsif params[:action] == 'create'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit(registration_params)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Try It.